# It is possible to replace the city field in billing information using Xtento Custom Attributes plugin?

Tags: custom-attributes, plugin

I'm using Xtento Custom Attributes and I'm trying to replace the City field in both billing and shipping addresses but I just got a new field instead of a replacement, is there any way to replace this field using this plugin? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to ask the support team
Link: https://www.xtento.com/contacts

Or maybe this blog post helps you
Link: https://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/show-hide-fields-ex-street-city-region-country-in-checkout-page

Thanks